# Export content of a SQLite3 table in CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, sqlite

I have a Ruby script that generates a SQLite3 database.

I want to be able to generate an "output.csv" file containing one of the database tables.

Is there a way to handle that in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy with [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) and [`to_csv`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-to_csv):

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite
# since Sequel 3.48.0 to_csv is deprecated, 
# we must load the to_csv feature via a extension
DB.extension(:sequel_3_dataset_methods) #define to_csv 
DB.create_table(:test){
  Fixnum :one
  Fixnum :two
  Fixnum :three
}
#Prepare some test data
5.times{|i|
  DB[:test].insert(i,i*2,i*3)
}

File.open('test.csv', 'w'){|f|
  f << DB[:test].to_csv
}
```

The result is:

```
one, two, three
0, 0, 0
1, 2, 3
2, 4, 6
3, 6, 9
4, 8, 12
```

In my test I had problems with line ends, so I needed an additional `gsub`:

```
File.open('test.csv', 'w'){|f|
  f << DB[:test].to_csv.gsub("\r\n","\n")
}
```

If you want the export without the header line, use `to_csv(false)`

Remarks:

- `.to_csv` is deprecated since Sequel 3.48.0 (2013-06-01).
  You may use an old version with `gem 'sequel', '< 3.48.0'` or load the extension `sequel_3_dataset_methods`).

---

To get support for other seperators and other CSV-features you may use a combination of Sequel and CSV:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'csv'
#Build test data
DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table(:test){
  Fixnum :one
  Fixnum :two
  Fixnum :three
  String  :four
}
#Prepare some test data
5.times{|i|
  DB[:test].insert(i,i*2,i*3, '<a href="www.test.com">test, no %i</a>' % i)
}

#Build csv-file
File.open('test.csv', 'w'){|f|
  DB[:test].each{|data| 
    f << data.values.to_csv(:col_sep=>';')
  }
}
```

Result:

```
0;0;0;"<a href=""www.test.com"">test, no 0</a>"
1;2;3;"<a href=""www.test.com"">test, no 1</a>"
2;4;6;"<a href=""www.test.com"">test, no 2</a>"
3;6;9;"<a href=""www.test.com"">test, no 3</a>"
4;8;12;"<a href=""www.test.com"">test, no 4</a>"
```

As an alternative you may patch Sequel::Dataset (modified code from a post of [marcalc at Github](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/issues/577)):

```
class Sequel::Dataset
    require 'csv'
    #
    #Options: 
    #* include_column_titles: true/false. default true
    #* Other options are forwarded to CSV.generate
    def to_csv(options={})
      include_column_titles = options.delete(:include_column_titles){true}  #default: true
      n = naked
      cols = n.columns
      csv_string = CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << cols if include_column_titles
        n.each{|r| csv << cols.collect{|c| r[c] } }
      end
      csv_string
    end 
end
```

Comment: Well, commas and line ends could be a problem, since I will have user generated html code in my fields. The sqlite built in ".mode csv" is quite good to escape commas and line ends, is there a way to call it directly from ruby?

Comment: I extended my answer. The example uses another column separator and " are masked.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Assume that model is an activerecord model
@secrets = Model.all
@csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
    @secrets.each { |secret|
            csv << ["#{secret.attr1.to_s}", "#{secret.attr2.to_s"] # and so on till your row is finished
    }
end
render :text => @csv, :content_type => 'application/csv'
```

If you have further problems, leave a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure. If I export a csv from the sqlite3 command line it will handle escaping commas inside fields, newlines etc. Is your method safe enough handling html code inside fields?

Comment: It should be. You just need to manage your database using [activerecord](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord)

Comment: If it's a non-Rails code-base then Active Record has little advantage over Sequel.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an update for 2020.  Since Sequel v5, `sequel_3_dataset_methods` has been completely removed and is unavailable.  As such, generating a CSV as a Database extension has also been completely removed.

It appears the current "best practice" is to add the `csv_serializer` plugin to a `Sequel::Model` class.  There is a catch here though, that the `Sequel::Model` class you define **must** be defined after the call to `Sequel.connect`.  The act of subclassing Sequel::Model invokes a read from the database.

This prevents a typical workflow of pre-defining your classes as part of any generic Gem.

According to the Sequel author, the preferred way to do this is through `MyClass = Class.new(Sequel::Model(:tablename))` in-line, or otherwise only calling `require` within your method definitions.

Making no promises about efficiency, here is a code sample that defines 'best practice'

```rb
require 'sequel'
require 'csv'

module SequelTsv
  class One
    def self.main
      db = Sequel.connect('sqlite://blog.db') # requires sqlite3

      db.create_table :items do
        primary_key :id
        String :name
        Float :price
      end

      items = db[:items] # Create a dataset

      items.insert(:name => 'abc', :price => rand * 100)
      items.insert(:name => 'def', :price => rand * 100)
      items.insert(:name => 'ghi', :price => rand * 100)

      item_class = Class.new(Sequel::Model(:items))

      item_class.class_eval do
        plugin :csv_serializer
      end

      tsv = item_class.to_csv(write_headers: true, col_sep:"\t")
      CSV.open('output.tsv', 'w') do |csv|
        CSV.parse(tsv) do | c |
          csv << c
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

SequelTsv::One.main
```

output:

```
id  name    price
1   abc 39.307899453608364
2   def 99.28471503410731
3   ghi 58.0295131255661
```