# Is it possible to generate a CSV using hashes as rows?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a big array of hashes, like this

```
# note that the key order isn't consistent
data = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3},
  {foo: 11, baz: 33, bar: 22}
]
```

I want to turn this into a CSV

```
foo,bar,baz
1,2,3
11,22,33
```

I am doing so like this:

```
columns = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << columns
  data.each do |d|
    row = []
    columns.each do |column|
      row << d[column]
    end
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? What I'd like to do is something like...

```
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << [:foo, :bar, :baz]
  data.each do |row|
    csv.add_row_hash row
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you have a big array of hashes? Any possibility you can skip that step and generate CSV at the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the appropriate options passed to generate, you can achieve what you want. Note that you can add the hash directly to the CSV once the headers are set.

```
c = CSV.generate(:headers => [:foo, :bar, :baz], :write_headers => true) do |csv|
  data.each { |row| csv << row }
end
```

Output:

```
foo,bar,baz
1,2,3
11,22,33
```

Comment: Holy s**t, it's directly supported by the library?! I googled and read the docs so much. Even now, reading the [docs for the options to new](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/CSV.html#method-c-new), it's not clear that the header info will be intelligently used when adding hashes as rows. Indeed, the [docs for `<<`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/CSV.html#method-i-3C-3C) imply that it cannot be given a Hash at all!

Comment: I agree, the docs are not that clear. It's actually in the [CSV::Row documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Comment: Is there some sense in which `CSV#<<` is the same thing as `CSV::Row#<<`? If not, then this isn't documenting it...

Comment: Agreed, it's missing from the `CSV#<<` documentation. The functionality is clearly there if you check the source.

Answer (score 1):

If keys can be missing, you need to get all the possible keys

```
keys = data.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq
```

Then map each row using those keys.

```
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << keys
  data.each do |row|
    csv << row.values_at(keys)
  end
end
```

Comment: The asker stated that the keys are not in the same order in each row.

Comment: I could sort the keys... but yeah, that introduces other problems and vulnerabilities. I can't control the order, for one thing. Also, if there are missing keys, the behavior won't be correct. So I have to populate each row with `nil` values for all keys that are in the header. and also make sure there are no keys that are NOT in the header (not a problem in most applications, but would be nice to not have to do that)

Comment: [`row.values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) might be useful here.

Comment: @muistooshort `values_at` does indeed return nil if the hash has no value, so this may be perfect, thanks!

Comment: @JohnBachir So does `row[k]`, I just think `values_at` reads better because it is talking about encoding the `row` rather than doing something with the keys.

Comment: `CSV::Row#<<`, which can take a hash, might be useful here.

Answer (score -1):

My first idea: Your `data` could be used to insert data into a database table.
If you combine this with a [csv-output of a DB-table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595486/676874) you have another solution.

Example:

```
data = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3},
  {foo: 11, baz: 33, bar: 22},
  {foo: 11, baz: 33, bar: 22, xx: 3}, #additional parameters are no problem
]

#Prepare DB as a helper
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.extension(:sequel_3_dataset_methods) #define to_csv 
DB.create_table(:tab){
  add_column :foo
  add_column :bar
  add_column :baz
}

DB[:tab].multi_insert(data) #fill table
#output as csv (the gsub is necessary on Windows, maybe not necessary on other OS
puts DB[:tab].to_csv.gsub("\r\n","\n")
```

Disadvantage: You need Sequel

Advantage: You can adapt the order quite easy:

```
puts DB[:tab].select(:bar, :baz).to_csv.gsub("\r\n","\n")
```