# Sequel to_csv generates file with hash instead of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sequel

Everytime I save using Sequel's `to_csv`, it gives me the object like below in CSV:

```
2.1.0 :033 > @order.radcheck.to_csv
 => "#<Radcheck:0x0000000697bb38>,#<Radcheck:0x0000000697ba20>\n" 
2.1.0 :034 > @orders.to_csv
 => "#<Order:0x000000069ee4d0>,#<Order:0x000000069ee318>,#<Order:0x000000069ee110>,#<Order:0x000000069ede68>,#<Order:0x000000069edc38>,#<Order:0x000000069edaa8>\n" 
2.1.0 :035 > @order.radcheck.class
 => Array 
2.1.0 :036 > @orders.class
 => Array

2.1.0 :038 > @order.radcheck
 => [#<Radcheck @values={:id=>2, :username=>"19cw5212443948", :attribute=>"User-Password", :op=>":=", :value=>"R65B60178yS", :order_id=>2}>, #<Radcheck @values={:id=>3, :username=>"D83d6raf47", :attribute=>"User-Password", :op=>":=", :value=>"90S4449y7845", :order_id=>2}>]

2.1.0 :039 > @order.radcheck.to_csv_file
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_csv_file' for #<Array:0x00000006981150>
    from (irb):39
    from /var/www/quadifi_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /var/www/quadifi_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /var/www/quadifi_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /var/www/quadifi_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /var/www/quadifi_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Also, I created a custom `to_csv_file` method but that doesn't work. The resulting CSV file would be like this.[image]

```
class Order < Sequel::Model
  plugin :validation_helpers
  plugin :nested_attributes
  plugin :timestamps, :update_on_create => true
  many_to_one :user
  one_to_many :radcheck

  nested_attributes :radcheck

  def self.to_csv_file(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv.add_row column_names
      @order.radcheck.all.each do |foo|
        values = foo.attributes.values
        csv.add_row values
      end
    end
  end

  def validate
    super
    validates_presence [ :time_limit, :ticket_count ]
  end
end


Class Radcheck < Sequel::Model(:radcheck)
  plugin :nested_attributes

  one_to_one :radusergroup
  many_to_one :user

  nested_attributes :radusergroup

end
```

I checked that my Sequel version 4.28.0 has `to_csv` depreceated so I am puzzled why I have `to_csv` giving Ruby symbol output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While it's not a duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16592661/128421 should be of good use.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not `to_csv` itself, but the model.

A small example:

```
require 'csv'

class A
end

puts [A.new, A.new].to_csv
```

The result:

```
#<A:0x00000002fa0148>,#<A:0x00000002fa00d0>
```

`to_csv` takes every element of the array and add the String-representation to the csv-line.

If you define another String-represenation with `to_s` you get a better result.

Example:

```
require 'csv'

class A
  def to_s
    'a'
  end
end

puts [A.new, A.new].to_csv
```

Result:

```
a,a
```

In your case something like this will help:

```
Class Radcheck < Sequel::Model(:radcheck)
  #...
  def to_s
    "Radcheck:..." #Add here some attributes of your table
  end
end
```

You have to replace  `"Radcheck:..."` with some dato you want to add to your csv.

---

About your problem with

```
2.1.0 :039 > @order.radcheck.to_csv_file
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_csv_file' for #<Array:0x00000006981150>
```

`to_csv_file` is define in `Order`, so you may try `@order.to_csv_file`.