# Using ruby to write out to a csv file from sqlite database

Tags: ruby, csv

I could not figure out the functionality of the below Ruby program. I know we are opening xxx.csv & creating 9 columns, but I don't understand the following:

`out <<`, `do |out|`, `(1..10).map{|i| "r" + i.to_s}` (1..10 rep a set of 1 to 10 ???), `map` method and its argument, and `flatten.join("\t") + "\n"`.

```
File.open("xxxx.csv", "w") do |out|
out << [
    'x', 'y', 'l', 'b', 
    'r', 'v', (1..10).map{|i| "r" + i.to_s}, 
    'xxx', 'd'
].flatten.join("\t") + "\n"
```

Example of the data: `13/#137/2011/0/15/5.8/5/4.....2..4/PG`

I'm learning Ruby and programming in general and apologize if my question is a basic one.

Thanks
Amy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also [Export content of a SQLite3 table in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592661/export-content-of-a-sqlite3-table-in-csv?noredirect=1&lq=1) to get an answer on your problem.

---

But to explain the code. Lets try it in parts:

```
p (1..10).map{|i| "r" + i.to_s}
```

result:

```
["r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8", "r9", "r10"]
```

Now lets do it in details: 
`(1..10)` is a Range object. If you execute

```
(1..10).to_a
```

you get get an array from 1 to 10: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

`map` loops on the objects of the range and and creates a new array with the result of the given block. So `(1..10).map{|i| "r" + i.to_s}` loops on all values of the range 1 to 10, gives the value to the block internal variable `i` and builds a new String with `r` and (`+`) the string representation of the number `i` (`to_s` means to string).

In total you get an array like this:

```
["x", "y", "l", "b", "r", "v", 
   ["r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8", "r9", "r10"], 
  "xxx", "d"
]
```

---

`flatten` makes array flat. If there is an array in an array, then `flatten` resolve the inner array(s) and makes it 'flat'

Example:

```
[1,[2,3]].flatten  #[1, 2, 3]
```

`join` takes all entries of the array and concatenates them into a string. The (optional) parameter defines the content between two elements. So in your code you get all entries as a csv-line with tab-separartor.

And in the end a newline is added.

In steps:

```
["x", "y", "l", "b", "r", "v", 
   ["r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8", "r9", "r10"], 
  "xxx", "d"
].flatten
```

results in

```
["x", "y", "l", "b", "r", "v", 
   "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8", "r9", "r10", #No inner array any longer
  "xxx", "d"
]
```

Then the join is done:

```
["x", "y", "l", "b", "r", "v", 
   "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8", "r9", "r10", 
  "xxx", "d"
].join("\t")
```

result:

```
"x\ty\tl\tb\tr\tv\tr1\tr2\tr3\tr4\tr5\tr6\tr7\tr8\tr9\tr10\txxx\td"
```